# JavaScriptCore Hello world nightly

Tags: javascript, c++, linux, macos, javascriptcore

I'm trying to develop a simple cli tool example using JavaScriptCore C API (to use in my linux machine or if not possible to use it in a mac osx). Argument is JavaScript code snippet.

```
    JSGlobalContextRef ctx;
    JSStringRef script;
    bool isOk;
    JSValueRef result;
    char *js;
    ctx = JSGlobalContextCreate(NULL);
    script = JSStringCreateWithUTF8CString("myscript");
    isOk = JSCheckScriptSyntax(ctx, script, NULL, 1, NULL);
    result = JSEvaluateScript(ctx, script, NULL, NULL, 1, NULL);
    JSStringRelease(script);
    JSGarbageCollect(ctx);
    JSGlobalContextRelease(ctx);
```

Should be something like this (just an example if you have better example I appreciate),I'm just writing the JS output once executed to stdout. I would like also to link against nightly build however always I did a build links against my system JavaScriptCore.framework.

Comment: sad no answer so far

Answer (score 0):

I just started to use JavascriptCore C API and this is my HelloWorld code:

```
JSGlobalContextRef context = JSGlobalContextCreate(0);
JSValueRef exception;
JSStringRef code = JSStringCreateWithUTF8CString("function helloWorld() { return 1+1; } helloWorld();");
JSStringRef file = JSStringCreateWithUTF8CString("");
JSValueRef  value = JSEvaluateScript(context, code, /* thisObject*/ 0, file, 1, &exception);
bool assert = JSValueIsNumber(context, value);
int number = (int)JSValueToNumber(context, value, NULL);
printf("Value: %d\n", number);
```

And I found this article that is helping me with binding native objects with Javascript.

https://karhm.com/JavaScriptCore_C_API/

I hope this help.

Cheers.